How can I install a vanity cabinet around existing plumbing?
I am working on a renovation and I am at a loss of how to install a vanity here. The plumbing comes up through the floor and is then piped for two sinks. I’ve searched high and low for a vanity that is open on the interior without drawers or shelves but cannot find one. I’ve searched kitchen cabinets for sinks but can’t find a granite countertop that would fit the kitchen cabinet. Should I hire a plumber to reconfigure the plumbing? Can I reconfigure somehow?
The width is 75” so ideally a 72” dual sink would go in there but would even go for a 60” at this point.
Any help is greatly appreciated!


I think what you have is probably not to code as-is anyway, so you'll need to bring a plumber in (or someone that knows plumbing), as I do not see any venting to the visible plumbing.  So you'll need to redo your plumbing anyway.  What you may end up needing to do is to get some sort of narrow table that only has legs at the corners, and cut in holes for the sinks and fixtures.

What is surrently supporting the sinks?

Your question is a bit broad for this site--you seem to be asking about both cabinetry and plumbing. Please see [ask] and take the [tour], then revise to ask just one clear question.

2 sink cabinet units at 36 inches wide would cover a 72 inch space, and add 2 units of 1 1/2 inch fillers or a single 3 inch filler to get to 75 inches.
A quick web-search "36 inch sink cabinet" showed several examples of cabinets that did not have drawers in them. These cabinets were either a pair of doors only, or a pair of doors with a false front above them.
You would have to run the plumbing through the middle sides of the two cabinets, but you may be reconfiguring the plumbing anyway, per Milwrdfan's comment that the pluming you have may not be to code. As a guess, if the first elbow above the vertical drain pipe were replaced with a sanitary tee, then the new top port on the tee continued to a plumbing vent, the drain might be code-worthy.
FWIW having the drain go through the floor of a cabinet is not a problem: that happens in kitchen islands in new construction. Drain plumbing is very often hand-assembly without glue or permanent joints past the vent connection in the wall or floor, so putting pipes through the side or bottom of a cabinet is not difficult.

I don't see any  big problem.  You have a 75 inch space and want a 72 inch cabinet.  Perfect.  There is no reason to compromise on that.  You have a drain entering the floor, that will create an S-trap.  There are solutions for that.
Most (all?) cabinets with drawers have enough space behind the drawers to run pipes.  You will need to cut a hole in the floor of the cabinet.  You can buy almost any 72 inch cabinet and use  combination of tubular and PVC piping to route all the pipes along the inside back wall of the cabinet, then down to the floor and connect to your drain.
Just don't pick a cabinet with floor-level bottom drawers beneath the sinks because the right side one will clash with the drain.
Here is an example:

The sink has 1-1/4" tubular drain connected to 2" PVC.  The PVC runs along the back of the double cabinet (yellow arrow), behind the middle set of drawers, and connects to the other sink.   I cut three notches in the bottom shelf for the pipes.  The shutoff valves can be accessed  beneath the bottom shelf, they are not hidden.
In this example the drain then goes into the wall where it is vented, so it's not exactly as yours will be.  But for you, the simplest solution would be to add an air admittance valve above the last elbow you see in this picture.
The arrangement in my photo isn't perfect, but it works perfectly.  You can do even better.
NOTE: There was briefly a comment that AAVs are not permitted everywhere.  If that is true in your location, you'll need a local expert to guide you, and you'll need to know exactly what's beneath the floor.  If the pipe is short, and quickly joins a 3" or 4" drain that is vented, it might be ok.  It may or may not be to code, but there are millions, and millions of sinks all over the world plumbed that way without siphoning.  A local plumber familiar with your local inspector will know.
